# How can I make a player-interactable bookshelf?

Tags: assets, modding, skyrim-modding

In the player's house `Interiors->WhiterunBrezeehouse` (`FormID 000165A8`) I duplicated a bookshelf (`CommonShelf03 FormID 000ce784` near the fire pit) and the book proxies, container, triggers, collision boxes, et cetera.

When I enter the house the duplicated book shelve is there and it shows the `"E to interact"` text, but when I press `E` nothing happens (I'm supposed to get up the book shelf manager).

Any clue of what it might be? What do I need to support proper interaction between a player and the shelf?

Comment: Although your question is on-topic, we don't get a lot of Skyrim Creation Kit questions here and you may get a faster response from more targeted sources, such as the [official creation kit forum](http://forums.bethsoft.com/forum/184-the-creation-kit/), or the [related Steam group](http://steamcommunity.com/groups/SkyrimCKPublic/discussions).

Comment: Thank you, I will try the mod forum as well... However I do like the StackExchange platform much more. I can only cross my fingers that more modders find this forum ;)

Answer (score 3):

Copying and pasting the bookshelves tends to be problematic; the resuling objects, as you have noticed, tend to not function properly. Instead, I'd recommend creating one from scratch.

Creating an interactive bookshelf from scratch involves:

- Placing the actual bookshelf object.
- Placing some `DefaultBook` objects on the shelf.
- Create a `PlayerBookshelfContainer`.
- Create `PlayerBookshelfClickTrigger` trigger with the bookshelf object (the in-game one) selected. Resize the trigger volume to cover the surface of the shelf you are making intractable (this trigger is the thing a player will actually interact with in-game).
- Create `PlayerBookshelfTrigger` trigger (with the bookshelf selected again). Resize this trigger to fill the volume of the shelf and enclose the books, more or less.
- Using the Link References tab available by double-clicking the bookshelf container, add reference links to each book you placed above. Use `BookshelfN` (where *N* is 1 to 18) as the keyword for each link.
- Similarly, link the click trigger to the container object. The keyword is `BookshelfContainer`. In the primitive tab, make sure the trigger supports player activation.
- Link the other trigger to the container; you don't need a keyword for this reference. Ensure, in the primitive tab, the trigger type is `L_TRIGGER`.
- Finally, link the *container* back to the trigger above (not the click one, the regular one). Use `BookshelfTrigger01` as the keyword.

That should cover the basics. For extra credit, you probably want to set up collision barriers between the placed books so they don't move around, and hide the actual container object outside the world slightly. You have to repeat this for each shelf. It's a bit tedious.

If you really want to try to debug the cloned bookshelves you've created, I'd go through the above steps with them and make sure all the links are in place, and that your click trigger volume is accessible, and so on.